# Concat words in rambda

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
const original = {
  speakers: {
    name: 'Author',
    words: [
      { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', time: '0.660000',   speaker: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.150000', name: 'the',    time: '1.020000',   speaker: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.380000', name: 'rat',    time: '1.170000',   speaker: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.770000', name: '.',      time: '1.550000',   speaker: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', time: '89.820000',  speaker: 'p1-0' },
      { duration: '0.390000', name: 'stood',  time: '90.180000',  speaker: 'p1-0' },
      { duration: '0.090000', name: 'and',    time: '90.570000',  speaker: 'p1-0' }
    ]
  }
}

const R = require('ramda');

const wordsPath = R.lensPath(['transcript', 'words']);

const wordsSpeakers = R.pipe(
  R.view(wordsPath),
  R.groupBy(R.prop('para')),
  R.map(R.map(R.dissoc('para'))),
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(R.zipObj(['para', 'words']))
)(Transcript);
console.log(wordsSpeakers)
```

that returns:

```
[
  {
    speaker: 'p0-0',
    words: [
        {
            duration: '0.360000',
            name: 'Arthur',
            time: '0.660000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.150000',
            name: 'the',
            time: '1.020000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.380000',
            name: 'rat',
            time: '1.170000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.770000',
            name: '.',
            time: '1.550000'
        }
    ]
},
{
    speaker: 'p1-0',
    words: [
        {
            duration: '0.360000',
            name: 'Arthur',
            time: '89.820000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.390000',
            name: 'stood',
            time: '90.180000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.090000',
            name: 'and',
            time: '90.570000'
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I modify the code so that the actual paragraphs for each speaker are added to the array list for each speaker?

so that I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    speaker: 'p0-0',
    words: [
        {
            duration: '0.360000',
            name: 'Arthur',
            time: '0.660000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.150000',
            name: 'the',
            time: '1.020000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.380000',
            name: 'rat',
            time: '1.170000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.770000',
            name: '.',
            time: '1.550000'
        }
    ].
    paragraph: `Arthur the rat.
},
{
    speaker: 'p1-0',
    words: [
        {
            duration: '0.360000',
            name: 'Arthur',
            time: '89.820000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.390000',
            name: 'stood',
            time: '90.180000'
        },
        {
            duration: '0.090000',
            name: 'and',
            time: '90.570000'
        }
    ],
    paragraph: `Arthur stood and.`
  }
]
```

Basically I would like to know if for each `words` list of array objects is created  in rambda 6?